# float-left of div and image

Tags: html, css

I try to float the div with the "testtext" next of the image, but it doesn't work.

I think I do a simple mistake but I can't find the reason :-)

```html
<div class="module-boxs">
  <div style="display:inline-flex;"">
     <img class="float-left" src="logo.jpg">
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-flex;">
  <h4>Modulename</h4>
     <h5>Web Dewloper</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put everything in a div and use display:inline-flex to display the contents in-line with each other

```
<div>
  <div style="display:inline-flex;">1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-flex;">2</div>
  <div style="display:inline-flex;">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i try that, i have the problem that the content of the second div (1 h1 text and 1 h2 text) will be display in the same line too. Also i try with a br between both texts but the result was the same - how can i do a linebreak into the second div, if i use the inline-flex style?

Comment: Put the elements you want to display in-line in one div and put the rest in another div. So, elements in first div will display in one line and the ones in the next div will be displayed below it.

Comment: please have a look at my post, i've update the code, what i have to do that the h4 und h5 text is not display in the same line?

Comment: Put h5 in a sperate div like this:
<div class="module-boxs">
<div style="display:inline-flex;" "="">                       
  <img class="float-left" src="http://wp1076647.server-he.de/v2/crm/uploads/company/logo.jpg"><h4>Modulename</h4>
</div>
<div>  
    <h5>Web Dewloper</h5>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: flex` but `flex`  is not supported in older browsers such IE10. You have to edit your HTML structure so it would be easier. Here you have an example:

```css
.module-name {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.module-name:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.module-name img.logo {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.module-name .text{
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.module-name .text h4 {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.module-name .text h5 {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 module-box">
  <div class="module-boxs">
    <div class="module-name">
      <img class="logo" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>Modulename</h4>
        <h5>Web Dewloper</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    <button class="btn">text</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, what i have to do that the text from h5 and h4 will float beside the image? How i do that in a responsive way?

Comment: Hi! You can insert `h5` inside module-name class and add `display: inline-block` style like `h4`.

Comment: i try this, but it dosen't work. .module-name h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.module-name h5 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 28px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

Comment: The problem is that the width of the text is limited by the width of the box so you have two options: make the text small or set the width of the box depending on the content you have in it. Here yo can see it https://jsfiddle.net/5796zhbo/6/

Comment: thats not the problem. the result is that the both texts are display inline and not over two lines.

Comment: Now I understand. I think that here you have the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5796zhbo/18/